# What are the steps of replacing bathroom tub/shower fixtures and diverter valve?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

[image]

- I've removed the old bathtub spout and shower head
- I'm unsure who the manufacture is for the diverter and valve
- The old fixture was a Single Handle Tub/Shower Ball-Type Faucet
- The old shower head was a "Speakman Anystream"
  [image]
- I accidentally broke the copper pipe to the bath spout inside the wall
- I was going to solder a new copper pipe for the one that I broke but I'm unsure if I need to replace the entire valve body
  [image]

**Questions:**

- Do I need to replace the entire valve body? Or just where there is the 3 small copper pipes?
- What is the part that's inside the tub spout that has 3 holes? (Is that the diverter? Can I just remove it and install a new diverter inside the valve? Or is that part of the valve itself?)
- If I don't need to replace the valve what are the next steps to take?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depending on what replacement tub spout you get, you may want to change to threaded brass or stainless steel pipe for the last bit - some are made for threaded pipe, some slip on to copper tubing.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks!  So the valve is where the handle connects?  And the Diverter is in the tub spout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to replace the valve. The tub spout has the diverter built into itself. Mixed hot and cold water from the valve will go down into the tub spout until you pull up the diverter knob on the tub spout which blocks the water flow and forces the water to exit through the shower head.

The tub spout is entirely separate from the valve. The 3 holes you see in the **valve** are the inlet ports for the hot and cold water and the exit port from the valve for the hot and cold "mixed" water. If you are going to replace the valve it is the entire thing you replace. All the way to the 1/2" threaded copper pipes that go into each of the 4 sides of the valve.

If you do not plan on replacing the valve then the next steps would be to repair the line to the tub spout. Then make sure you can find replacement trims  for the valve- unless you are going to reuse the old trims in which case you are all good.

Comment: And what isn't particularly obvious to most people meeting one for the first time is that the 3rd hole in the valve connects equally to top and bottom pipes out of the valve body, which is *why* "the diverter is in the tub spout" works. You plug the tub outlet, and water backs up through the valve body until it hits the shower head.